# Generate https image URL

Tags: views, 8, entities, uri

In order to generate full path of images(URL) on views for rest endpoint on my decoupled Drupal project I'm using [Image Url Formatter module](https://www.drupal.org/project/image_url_formatter), everything works correctly until I decide to put the website on HTTPS, In console I see
`Loading mixed (insecure) display content 
“http://core.domain.com/sites/default/files/styles/874x492/public/gallery/2017-01/1-907331.JPG?itok=MKfQSWFh” on a secure page`

it's because this formatter return *HTTP* Instead *HTTPS* for image URLs.

**In the situation like this that the websites should work on HTTPS and HTTP both, I advise  my team using `//domain.com`  instead of `http://domain.com` or `https://domain.com` in all endpoint URLS**

Now I looking for a solution to return all images URL from `http://....` to `//...` . if I had few views I could benefit REWRITE feature of view but I have a lot of views rest export endpoint.

What is your solution for this requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Doing a quick test, works fine with HTTPS

[image]

Views REST XML

[image]

Views REST Json

[image]

All of the above is using FULL URL

[image]

Perhaps someone set it to Absolute file path, which will give you `/path/image.jpg` (with out the $base_url). Then in some template file they did `http://example.com{{ field.image.content }}`

**update**

using `template_preprocess_image_formatter()` is another solution to change the template formatter of the image.

Comment: as I mentioned in the question I know I can do this for each view one by one, but there are several view and I looked for a global solution,

Comment: @zhilevan and what I am saying is that it should've worked had your people set things up properly. Why do you have a lot of views? Are you not using Contextual Filters?

Comment: I think create working with `template_preprocess_image_formatter()` is  better solution and there,  replace all `http://`  with `//`